# How can I populate a dropdown menu with Mongodb in Meteor javascript?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

is there a way I can populate a dropdown list with values stored in Mongodb? For example, if I have a `car` object that has a `color` attribute that could contains values: `black', 'red` or `blue`, I want the dropdown list to contain those values. I need to do this in Meteor javascript.

Thank you.

Comment: what did you tried? what is not working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

without any dependencies you can do simply

```
<select name="sss">
 {{#each colors}}
    <option>{{this}}</option>
{{/each}}
</select>

Template.mytemplate.helpers({
   colors: function(){
    return Colors.find().map(function (doc) {
      return doc.name
    })
 }
});
```

Comment: how can i relate that to the `cars` object though? i need the color attribute to save to the `cars` object.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest and cleanest way is to use [`aldeed:autoform`](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform). `autoform` relies on [`aldeed:simple-schema`](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema) and [collection2](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2). With these packages you can do this:

```
Cars = new Mongo.Collection('Cars')

Cars.attachSchema({
  color: {
    type: String,
    allowedValues: ['red', 'black', 'green']
  }
})
```

Now let's assume you have a collection called `Colors` and all these documents have a value `name`:

```
function getColors () {
  return Colors.find().map(function (doc) {
    return doc.name
  })
}

Cars.attachSchema({
  color: {
    type: String,
    allowedValues: getColors()
  }
})
```